# AVPlayerStatus for local file not ready

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, avplayer

I'm having some trouble with playback of a local .wav file. My `AVPlayerStatus` is printing `0`, which i'm assuming means it's not ready to play. I can't seem to figure it out but having said that, this is my first time trying to use anything to do with AVPlayer so it's probably something simple. I'd appreciate any help. Here's the code:

***i should add that my sounds are not playing!***

```
-(void) playWordSound:(UILabel *)label
{
    NSString *path;
    switch (label.tag)
    {
        case 1:
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"humpty" ofType:@"wav"];
            break;
        case 2:
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dumpty" ofType:@"wav"];
            break;
        case 3:
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"saty" ofType:@"wav"];
            break;
        case 4:
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"on 2" ofType:@"wav"];
            break;
        case 5:
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a 3" ofType:@"wav"];
            break;
        case 6:
            path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wall" ofType:@"wav"];
            break;
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVQueuePlayer *player;
    static const NSString *ItemStatusContext;
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    NSLog(@"%d",player.status);
    [player play];
}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Sound finished");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some important gotchas Apple is pointing out when using AVPlayItem [-initWithURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayerItem/initWithURL:) method:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> This method immediately returns the item, but
> with the status AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown.
>
> If the URL contains valid data that can be used by the player item,
> the status later changes to AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay.
>
> If the URL contains no valid data or otherwise can't be used by the
> player item, the status later changes to AVPlayerItemStatusFailed.

What I imagine is happening is, because you are sending a `-play` message not long after you create the AVPlayerItem object, its status is still `AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown` (same goes for the AVPlayer object) since it didn't receive enough time to load the resource and change status to `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`.

My sugestions:

- Either check for the AVPlayerItem/AVPlayer status change and call `-play` at a later stage;

OR, even simpler,

- Load an [AVAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or an [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVURLAsset) object from the NSURL and use the AVPlayerItem `–initWithAsset:` method, which should return a ready to play object, and then you call call `-play` immediately after, if you so please.

Comment: Initializing as an AVAsset fixed it! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`0` is equivalent to `AVPlayerStatusUnknown`, I assume this is because the player does not attempt to load the URL until you actually call `play`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVPlayerStatus):

> `AVPlayerStatusUnknown`
>
> Indicates that the status of the player is not yet known because it has not tried to load new media resources for playback.

Comment: I switched the code around so that `[player play]` is called before `player.status` and it's still outputting `0`. I should have mentioned in bold somewhere in my original post that the real problem is that the sounds are not playing!